# Java Loop star pattern - algorithm optimalization

Tags: java, loops

Can anyone tell me what is the more elegant solution for outputting this pattern? 
I most interested in my makeTemplate method, but any other help will be appreciated.
Here is my code, which i want to be more readable:

```
public class Main {

public static void makeTemplate(char tab[][], int rows, int col) {
    boolean increase = true;
    int j = 0;
     char star = '*';
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         if (increase) {
             tab[i][j] = star;
             if (j >= col - 1) {
                increase = false;
                 j--;
                continue;
             }
             j++;
        } else {
             tab[i][j] = star;
            if (j < 0 + 1) {
                 increase = true;
                 j++;
                continue;
             }
             j--;
        }
     }

 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
     char[][] tab = new char[30][6];
    makeTemplate(tab, 30, 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.print(tab[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please explain what your algorithm is doing. Also is there a reason why you are using `continue` statements?

Comment: No, there is no reason to use continue I hope- that's why i ask this question, to optimalize this.

Comment: Ok, so whats the program supposed to do? I put it into [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hNxjR4) and all I get is a bunch of stars on individual lines.

Comment: I don't know why your output is like this, it should print just a 'zig-zag' pattern of stars - my output is good on eclipse.

Comment: Alright i got that output in netbeans, must be ideone not printing blank characters. Ill post an answer soon with critiques. In the future i would suggest posting your code to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as this is a better place to ask for code critiques.

Comment: https://anotepad.com/notes/tr8c29 Yes, here is a pattern for which i looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Only made some changes to `makeTemplate`

```
public static void makeTemplate(char tab[][], int rows, int col) {
    boolean increase = true;
    int j = 0;
    char star = '*';
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        tab[i][j] = star;
        if (increase) {                
            if (j >= col - 1) {
                increase = false;
                j--;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        } else {                
            if (j < 1) {
                increase = true;
                j++;                    
            }else {
                j--;
            }                
        }
    }

}
```

Replaced the `continue` statements with `else` as the continue statement pretty much does the same thing as the else. Using continue in the if statement says to skip the `j++` or `j--` below. So instead the `j++` or `j--` will only be executed if the `if` is true.

I also changed `if(j < 0 + 1)` to `if(j < 1)` as `0+1` = `1`

Moved `tab[i][j] = star;` before the first `if` as it is the first line in the `if` and `else` - Thanks Betlista

Comment: also `tab[i][j] = star;` can be moved before `if` - it's the same in both branches...

Comment: @Betlista Very true, changed that.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant [java8](/questions/tagged/java8) solution:

```
IntStream.range(0, ROWS).forEach(i -> {
            int cur = i % (COLS * 2);
            if(cur < 6) {
                IntStream.range(0, cur).forEach(f -> System.out.print(" "));
            } else {
                IntStream.range(0, COLS - cur % COLS).forEach(f -> System.out.print(" "));
            }
            System.out.println("*");
        });
```

Granted, I haven't used the `makeTemplate()` method but as far as elegance and understand-ability goes, this does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
public static char[][] makeTemplate(char tab[][], int rows, int col, int curRow, int curPos, boolean increase) {
    if (curRow == rows)
        return tab;
    tab[curRow][curPos] = '*';
    if (increase && curPos + 1 == col) {
        increase = false;
    } else if (curPos == 0) {
        increase = true;
    }
    return makeTemplate(tab, rows, col, curRow + 1, (increase) ? ++curPos : --curPos, increase);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] tab = makeTemplate(new char[30][6], 30, 6, 0, 0, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.print(tab[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```